# I made a python program that prints out the first ten perfect squares but only one shows up

Tags: python-3.x

I made a program that is suppose to print the first ten perfect squares but only the last exponent shows up. This is my coding, it doesn't give me a error message which is good but I need all of the exponents to print out.

```
def main():
    Sqrs()

def Sqrs():
    import math
    lstSquares = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        math.pow(i,2)
    lstSquares.append(math.pow(i,2))
    ShowResults(lstSquares)

def ShowResults(lstSquares):
    print(lstSquares)

main()
```

Comment: I'm thinking you need to indent `lstSquares.append(math.pow(i,2))`

Answer (score 1):

Put the `.append()` inside the loop:

```
def main():
    Sqrs()

def Sqrs():
    import math
    lstSquares = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        math.pow(i,2)
        lstSquares.append(math.pow(i,2))
    ShowResults(lstSquares)

def ShowResults(lstSquares):
    print(lstSquares)

main()
```

Result:

```
[1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0, 36.0, 49.0, 64.0, 81.0, 100.0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I feel very stupid for not solving something that simple. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

`listSquares` is only having an item added to it after the loop is run through because it is not included in the loop. Include it by indenting it so that all of the squares will go into the list. Like so

```
for i in range(1,11):
    math.pow(i,2)
    lstSquares.append(math.pow(i,2))
ShowResults(lstSquares)
```